# How to hide UIElements for a specific cell in UITableView (Swift 5)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView and for it I created a cell in xib. This cell has a label and a button. I would like to display the label and hide the button under certain conditions for the cell I need. How can i do this?

```
extension SourcesViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
...
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SourceCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! SourceCell
        ...
return cell
}


class SourceCell: UITableViewCell {
...
@IBOutlet var logInLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var logOutButton: UIButton!
...
@IBAction func logInLogOutButton(_ sender: Any) {
    //When I press this button I want to hide log out button and show label for current cell
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Custom Cell

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myCustomLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myCustomButton : UIButton!
    
    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender : UIButton) {
        sender.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

TableView :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
        cell.myCustomLabel.text = "Row \(indexPath.row)"
        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
```

Here is what the output looks like :

[image]

Comment: After restarting the application, the buttons in all cells become hidden, and I need the buttons to be hidden only in specific cells

Comment: The comment in your codes says : *//When I press this button I want to hide log out button and show label for current cell* . If you add the above code in the `logInLogOutButton` function, the button should only get hidden when the button is pressed. If however, you have some other condition based on which you want to hide the button. You can check for the condition in `cellForRowAt` method and hide/show the button. Note however, you will need to create an @IBOutlet or assign a tag to your button so it can be accessed from `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: I have a problem that if I hide the button in @IBAction func logInLogOutButton(_ sender: Any), then it is hidden for all cells, and not only for the one on which I clicked the button

Comment: I have edited my answer with a working version of the code. I hope, I understood your requirement. If you are still facing issues, you might need to show me some more of your code. Upload to GitHub maybe?

Comment: But after restart your app, the state of table view doesn't save

Comment: Yes, that is expected. In the code above, we have not persisted that state of the cells anywhere. So when the app restarts it has no idea of what state the UI was in before.

If you want to maintain the state, you will need some sort of data structure (array maybe?) that stores the 'data' that corresponds to each cell and then repopulates the UI.